# NodeJs linkedin ,the client is not authorized error

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

```
var Linkedin = require('node-linkedin')(clientID, clientSecret);
app.get('/linked',function(req, res){
      Linkedin.auth.authorize(res,scope);
      Linkedin.auth.getAccessToken(res, req.query.code, req.query.state, function(err, results){
          if(err){
            console.log('error : ' + err);
          }
          console.log('results : ' + results);
          return;
      });
  });
```

Return to error code : unauthorized_client: the client is not authorized.
results:null.
help me for this problem

Comment: Did you check that your clientID and clientSecret are valid?

Comment: Yes , they are valid